# WTForm with more than one model object

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I have a page that should create an instance of two distinct models at the same time, ie, when the same form is submitted.

I created a form using [wtforms_alchemy](https://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) but this covers only one model, not both:

```
class RoutineForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Routine
        only = [u'name', u'comment']
        field_args = {u'comment': {'widget': TextArea()}, }
```

I know I could create a form that does not inherit from the model and includes all the fields I need but for the sake of keeping things DRY how can I have an instance of ModelForm use two models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple forms at the same time.  Give each a prefix to make sure the field names don't overlap in HTML.  Validate both forms.  Other than having two form objects, everything else is normal about the view and template.

```
class RoutineForm(ModelForm):
    ...

class EventForm(ModelForm):
    ...

@app.route('/make_event', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def make_event():
    routine_form = RoutineForm(prefix='routine')
    event_form = EventForm(prefix='event')

    if request.method == 'POST' and routine_form.validate() and event_form.validate():
        ...

     return render_template('make_event.html', routine_form=routine_form, event_form=event_form)
```